# gluUnProject not working

Tags: c++, opengl, glu

I am trying to use gluUnProject to get my mouse coordinates into world coordinates, however it seems to not be working, or I am just misunderstanding the functionality of the glUnProject function, here is the code I am working with, my matrices all check out fine and as for the -300 on the mouse x coordinate, I am using a C++ Win32 Dialog and the ScreenToClient is giving me funky results.

```
        int appWidth  = CApplication::GetInstance()->GetWidth();
        int appHeight = CApplication::GetInstance()->GetHeight();
        float fAspect = (float)appWidth / (float)appHeight;

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluPerspective(60.0f, fAspect, 0.1f, 100000.0f);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glTranslatef(m_vecCamera.x, -m_vecCamera.y, m_vecCamera.z);

        GLint viewport[4];
        GLdouble modelview[16];
        GLdouble projection[16];
        GLfloat winX, winY, winZ;
        GLdouble posX, posY, posZ;

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH);
        //Retrieve the Model/View, Projection, and Viewport Matrices
        glGetDoublev( GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview );
        glGetDoublev( GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection );
        glGetIntegerv( GL_VIEWPORT, viewport );

        //Retrieve the Mouse X and the flipped Mouse Y
        winX = (float)pInput->msg.param1-300.0f;
        winY = (float)viewport[3]-(float)pInput->msg.param2;
        glReadPixels( int(winX), int(winY), 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &winZ );

        gluUnProject(winX, winY, winZ, modelview, projection, viewport, &posX, &posY, &posZ);
```

This is however giving me coordinates relative to the center of my screen, and I am assuming is relative to my camera, I also tried implementing my own function

```
Vector2f MouseUnProject(int x, int y)
{

        GLint viewport[4];
        GLdouble modelview[16];
        GLdouble projection[16];
        GLfloat winX, winY, winZ;
        GLdouble posX, posY, posZ;

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH);
        //Retrieve the Model/View, Projection, and Viewport Matrices
        glGetDoublev( GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview );
        glGetDoublev( GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection );
        glGetIntegerv( GL_VIEWPORT, viewport );

        //Retrieve the Mouse X and the flipped Mouse Y
        winX = (float)x;
        winY = (float)viewport[3]-y;
        glReadPixels( int(winX), int(winY), 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &winZ );

        double projectionX, projectionY;
        double viewX, viewY;
        double worldX, worldY;

        //Convert from Screen Coords to Projection Coords
        projectionX = (double)winX / ((double)viewport[2]/2.0) - 1.0;
        projectionY = (double)winY / ((double)viewport[3]/2.0) + 1.0;

        //Convert from projection Coords to View Coords
        viewX = projectionX * modelview[14];
        viewY = projectionY * modelview[14];

        //Convert from View Coords to World Coords
        worldX = viewX + modelview[12];
        worldY = viewY - modelview[13];

        return Vector2f(worldX, worldY);

}
```

It works to a certain mount, but when moving the camera, the numbers instantly go off a bit, the conversion from projection to view coords 'seems' to be ok, and the projection coords are definitely good.

I would really prefer to use glUnProject rather then my own function, but I can't get it to work for the life of me and all of the google searches I found don't seem to answer my question. What exactly does the GL documentation mean by 'object space' perhaps my understanding of that is wrong, and if so what do I additionally have to do to get my coordinates in the right space?

Comment: You need to have some geometry to transform onto (e.g., what is your mouse over?--it doesn't make sense to transform to world coordinates, when there's nothing in your world).  You *are* drawing geometry, right?

Comment: I wanted to get the mouse coordinates at the camera Z (which starts at -100) relative to the world identity matrix, the GLU documentation is really vague on what this function does, I have set the projection matrix, and have reset the model/view matrix and applied the camera translation to it, I have a Map (Textured Quads) that begin at (0,0,0) and extends in one direction from there.

I was under the impression that this function would give me basically the position of my mouse before the view transform was applied, what is it that I am not seeing and how do I correctly use this function?

Comment: The mouse coordinates plus a depth give you the position of an object after the perspective divide (i.e., a screen coordinate: at such and such an (x,y) position and a certain depth into the screen).  What gluUnProject does is to convert this position *back* into the position of the original object.  So, if you draw a triangle, and a vertex from the triangle lands at pixel (124,89) with a depth of 0.647, then gluUnProject will be able to tell you the coordinates of that vertex.  I'm not really sure what your problem is, but then, I'm not really sure what you're asking.

Comment: Put simply, I have a map editor, I wish to retrieve the coordinates of my mouse in 3D space, My map starts at (0,0) and extends, lets say 1000 in the X and Y axes, I want my retrieved coordinates to say 0,0 in the top left of the map, and 1000, 1000 in the bottom right, regardless of the camera's translation, that is when my mouse is hovered over them

Comment: Good.  So, here's how it would work: you begin your frame.  You draw your map.  You sample the depth under your mouse.  You pass the mouse position and the depth to gluUnProject along with the current values of the modelview and projection matrices.  The result should be the position you want.  I suspect your problem was that you didn't render the object first, so your depth value was wrong.  You should be checking that with a print statement--it should change significantly when you mouse over your object.

Comment: Ok, so I am one step closer I think, what you said worked, I did the gluUnProject function right after drawing and it does work, when I draw a point at the coordinates given it all checks out, bare with me for one more question though, the coordinates that are being displayed to me don't seem to be right, for instance, when I draw my map, It is an identity matrix, then the camera translation, then I draw my quads which the first is only 1000x1000. I know the coords are correct as the point draws where the mouse is, but why are they different from what I pass into the glBegin

Comment: the coordinates by the way are really big, at what I was hoping to see 0,0 I got -15000, -9500, -97500. And even wierder at the other side of the map, I know it is 'correct' coordinates otherwise my point wouldn't draw in the right place, however what is the difference between the coords I have and the coords I want? And is there a solution getting the coords I want?

Answer (score 0):

was posted a year ago,but anyways....so you are getting coordinates relative the the screen because you made a call to gluPerspective. this call internally calls glfrustum which will generate normalized coordinates in the range {-1, 1}. However if you called glfrustum directly with your near/far values you would have got the result from gluUnproject in that range.

To get back to your map editor coordinates, simply take the result from gluUnproject and manually range convert back to your editor coordinate system, ie{-1,1} => {0, max}

To get started you should test gluUnProject by inputting (0,0), (midX, midY), (maxX, maxY) and the result from gluUnProject should be (-1, -1, depth), (0, 0, depth) and (1, 1, depth). If you setup the projection matrix using glFrustum then the above result will be returned in the near/far range.